# Custom attributes with Moshi Json Parser

Tags: java, json, moshi

What is Jackson's `@JsonAnySetter` and `@JsonAnyGetter` equivalent for Moshi?
Is there any way to handle custom attributes in Moshi ?

Answer (score 0):

With Moshi, it’s particularly easy to customize how values are converted to and from JSON. A type adapter is any class that has methods annotated @ToJson and @FromJson. [more](https://github.com/square/moshi#custom-type-adapters)

```
class CardAdapter {
  @ToJson String toJson(Card card) {
    return card.rank + card.suit.name().substring(0, 1);
  }

 @FromJson Card fromJson(String card) {
    if (card.length() != 2) throw new JsonDataException("Unknown card: " + card);

  char rank = card.charAt(0);
  switch (card.charAt(1)) {
    case 'C': return new Card(rank, Suit.CLUBS);
    case 'D': return new Card(rank, Suit.DIAMONDS);
    case 'H': return new Card(rank, Suit.HEARTS);
    case 'S': return new Card(rank, Suit.SPADES);
    default: throw new JsonDataException("unknown suit: " + card);
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Currently we use Svenson Json Provider with native support for custom attributes. Every class supports custom attributes. Would we have to write a Custom Adapter for every model class ?